# Problem with Laravel Collection sortBy function

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

I am trying to do a multiple sortBy on a collection and seems like is not working properly:

```
$myCollection = collect([
    ['foo' => 3, 'bar' => null, 'active' => 1],
    ['foo' => 2, 'bar' => null, 'active' => 1],
    ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 1, 'active' => 1],
])->sortBy('foo')->sortBy('bar')->sortBy('active');
```

Result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#417 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "foo" => 3
      "bar" => null
      "active" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "foo" => 2
      "bar" => null
      "active" => 1
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "foo" => 1
      "bar" => 1
      "active" => 1
    ]
  ]
}
```

First sorts properly by active (they are all the same = 1)

Then sorts properly by "bar" (null < 1)

Then sortBy('foo') fails, because (2<3), but shows 3 first before 2...
Expecting result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#417 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "foo" => 2
      "bar" => null
      "active" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "foo" => 3
      "bar" => null
      "active" => 1
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "foo" => 1
      "bar" => 1
      "active" => 1
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is a sample I did for the presentation. In my real scenario I am using Collection::macro  with custom function callbacks to compare dates... but even in this simple example things are looks like not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are chaining three different sortings, and in this case you can be sure only that last applied sort has been properly done.

So try to pass array of sort operations:

```php
$myCollection = collect(...)->sortBy([
    ['foo', 'asc'],
    ['bar', 'asc'],
    ['active', 'asc'],
]);
```

More info you can find in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sort).

Comment: Yes, thanks.
I just saw it. Thank you.

$myCollection = collect([
    ['foo' => 3, 'bar' => null, 'active' => 1],
    ['foo' => 2, 'bar' => null, 'active' => 1],
    ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 1, 'active' => 1],
]);

$sorted = $myCollection->sortBy([
    fn ($a, $b) => $a['active'] <=> $b['active'],
    fn ($a, $b) => $a['bar'] <=> $b['bar'],
    fn ($a, $b) => $a['foo'] <=> $b['foo'],
]);